# Using a String instead of an Enum Value in SwiftUI possible?

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, enums, contains

I try to avoid duplicating a `ZStack` 7 times by using a `ForEach` and everything works fine. But I can't replace `dates.contains(.Monday)` by `dates.contains(bubble.word)`.

I get an error as well: Instance method 'contains' requires the types 'Week' and 'String.Element' (aka 'Character') be equivalent.

I also tried `dates.contains(.\(bubble.word))`.

Is what I'm trying to do possible or not at all? Thanks!

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

enum Week {
    case Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday
}

struct Car: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let days: [Week]
}

let cars = [
    Car(name: "Peugeot 307", days: [.Monday, .Sunday]),
    Car(name: "Dacia Duster", days: [.Monday, .Sunday])
]

struct ParentView: View {
    let car: Car
    var body: some View {
        ChildView(dates: car.days)
    }
}

struct Bubble: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let letter: String
    let word: String
}

let bubbles = [
    Bubble(letter: "M", word: "Monday"),
    Bubble(letter: "T", word: "Tuesday"),
    // To Sunday
]

struct ChildView: View {
    let dates: [Week]
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(bubbles) { bubble in
            ZStack {
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(dates.contains(.Monday) ? .black : nil)
                    .frame(width: 22, height: 22)
                Text(bubble.letter)
                    .foregroundColor(dates.contains(.Monday) ? .white : .grey))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just declare `word` as `Week` in your `Bubble` struct.

Comment: I get an error with this solution `dates.contains(bubble.word)`: "'contains' is only available in iOS 16.0 or newer" where as I target iOS 15 and 16.

Comment: `.contains` has been around since iOS 8 so you must be doing something wrong or there is some info missing from your question.

Comment: You're right! I used `word: [Months]` instead of `word: Months`. It's working like a charm now.